# In runtime, how can I change the value of remoteEntry in the module federation (microfrontend)

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

If I change the value of environment variable in `remoteEntry` (e.g. change `baseUrl` for API calls), it needs to rebuild the `remoteEntry` with Webpack to have a new `remoteEntry` with new `baseUrl`, but I want to change the `baseUrl` in runtime without rebuilding.
How can I do this?